# Can't while loops be used on arrays in awk?

Tags: awk

For some reason the below is an infinite loop. The array length is 54. The input that `awk` gets is

```
DISK WARNING - free space: /dev 7946 MB (100.00% inode=100%); /dev/shm 7881 MB (99.01% inode=100%); /sys/fs/cgroup 7959 MB (100.00% inode=100%); / 3038 MB (19.00% inode=97%); /home 98386 MB (41.35% inode=-); /mnt/dat0 41888 MB (94.75% inode=98%); /mnt/nas3 265245 MB (51.80% inode=100%); /var/lib/docker/containers 3038 MB (19.00% inode=97%); /var/lib/docker/overlay2 3038 MB (19.00% inode=97%);| /dev=0MB;6356;7151;0;7946 /dev/shm=78MB;6367;7163;0;7959 /sys/fs/cgroup=0MB;6367;7163;0;7959 /=12951MB;12792;14391;0;15990 /home=139510MB;190780;214627;0;238475 /mnt/dat0=2316MB;35376;39798;0;44221 /mnt/nas3=246755MB;409600;460800;0;512000 /var/lib/docker/containers=12951MB;12792;14391;0;15990 /var/lib/docker/overlay2=12951MB;12792;14391;0;15990
```

**Code**

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -A -I '/run/*' -I '/tmp/*' | awk -F'|' '{
  gsub(/ /, ";", $2)
  gsub(/^;/, "", $2)
  split($2, a, "[;=]")

print "array length:" length(a)

i = 0
while(i < length(a)){
  print a[1+i*6]
  print a[2+i*6]
  print a[3+i*6]
  print a[4+i*6]
  print a[5+i*6]
  print a[6+i*6]
  print "---"
  i++
  }
}'
```

**Update

```
for (i in a) print a[i]
```

works, but then I can't print then out in groups of 6, as I can do with a while loop.

**Question**

Can someone see why it just doesn't print out the 54 elements?

Comment: what's the output for `print "array length:" length(a)`? IIRC, `length` of array only works in gawk ..

Comment: You're modifying the array during the loop by allocating elements.

Comment: @Sundeep 54. I get the same issue with gawk.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Can you explain why they get modified? Or perhaps how I else can get access to 6 of the element at one time?

Comment: you could use result of split... `len = split($2, a, "[;=]")` and then `while(i < len)` .. and not sure about `i++`, should it be `i+=6`?

Comment: How about using a regular for loop, `for (i = 1; i <= length(a); ++i)`, and then test for divisibility by 6 to add the `---`, with `if (!i%6){print "==="}`?

Comment: when you write `a[x]` in awk,  an array (hashtable)  element `a[x]` will be created, if x not in a.

Comment: @Kent How can it go past `length(a)` as I do `i < length(a)`?

Comment: At the start of the loop, the statement is true; then, during the loop, you allocate new elements, and the statement will still be true. Try a toy example that prints your whole array every loop to see how it grows.

Answer (score 0):

Since you multiply with 6 inside the loop, you have to divide with 6 on the outside.

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -A -I '/run/*' -I '/tmp/*' | awk -F'|' '{
  gsub(/ /, ";", $2)
  gsub(/^;/, "", $2)
  split($2, a, "[;=]")

i = 0
while(i < length(a)/6){
  print a[1+i*6]
  print a[2+i*6]
  print a[3+i*6]
  print a[4+i*6]
  print a[5+i*6]
  print a[6+i*6]
  i++
  }
}'
```

Comment: You could do `for (j=1;j<=6;j++) print a[j+i*6]` instead of writing 6 almost identical print statements. Also if you use `-F'|[[:space:]]*` then you can get rid of `gsub(/^;/, "", $2)`. Finally - the existing loop would be simpler and more natural as a for loop: `for (i=0; i<length(a)/6; i++)`. I actually think all this dividing and multiplying might be useless and you could just do something like `for (i=0; i<length(a); i+=6) for (j=1;j<=6;j++) print a[i+j]` but check the math!

Comment: If you replace split by gsub(";|=","\n",$2);print $2, no need of loop.